# Context Mapping and Open Host Services

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have a question regarding the modelling of bounded contexts and the context mapping.

I have to evaluete and document an existing architecture where two bounded contexts are exchanging information with message events (domain events).

Has the bounded context which sends the events an open host service? Or am I getting the open host service wrong and an open host service is just an API that another bounded context can access?

Comment: Are these integration events, send to some pub-sub service? If other bounded contexts were interested in these events, is there an easy way to subscribe and is there a clearly defined contract for the content of the events?

Comment: Yes, that is the case. The BC (and other BCs) can subscribe for the events. Therefore it is an OHS (in my opinion). If it is not the case I would only draw a straight line between the bounded contexts. Correct?

Comment: The key issue is: are these other BCs of yours that integrate with the event originator a part of your system (do you / your team have control over them), or are they somehow external integrations (developed/owned by other teams, a different company, or a legacy system you don't have control of)? The idea behind OHS is that many external (in the above sense) systems are integrating with, or are in high demand of, your system - so the interested parties get together and come up with a general-purpose protocol for this intercommunication, and make it *public* ("open") for integration purposes.

Comment: If that's not the case, then it's not an OHS, even though it might be operating as a set of services within the bounds of your system, and is used by several distinct parts of the system. So the first thing to understand (and document) is what constitutes "your system"; where does it begin and where does it end - make the boundaries explicit.

Comment: Thank you @FilipMilovanović for making things clear for me. All the systems are in our control.

Comment: Imo having many clients is not a requirement to call it an OHS. That’s just a reason to create one (instead of making a specific integration with each client). Imo it’s also not necessary to define the contract collaboratively. For example, a general purpose REST API could be considered an Open Host Service, even if there’s only a single other bounded contexts that uses that API. The key for me is that an OHS is not tailored for a single client; the upstream provides the OHS with a defined stable contract.